# How to prove that the operator is linear continuous and find its norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A:X\to Y$, where $X=C^1[0,1]$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|_{C^1}=\|f\|_u+\|f'\|_u$, and $Y=C[0,1]$ equipped with the uniform norm $\|f\|_u$ be defined as
$$(Af)(x)=f'(x);$$
I proved the linearity as follows:
$A(f+g)(x)=(f+g)'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x)=Af(x)+Ag(x);$
$A(\lambda f)(x)=(\lambda f)'(x)=\lambda f'(x)=\lambda A f(x)$
I do not understand how to prove continuity and find the norm

Comment: On what spaces is your operator acting? With what norms? Please post all relevant details of the problem.

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question. First you need to specify the domain and codomain of the map $A$.

Comment: @SuccessfulFailure  Corrected, wrote everything that was in the condition

Comment: @Jose27 Corrected

Comment: @AndrijMatviiv try to observe  the continuity at $0$.Can you produce a sequence of continuously differentiable function $(f_n)$ that converges to $0$ uniformly but $A(f_n) $ doesn't converges to $0$ ?

Comment: @SuccessfulFailure I don't understand you a little

Comment: You've gotten two conflicting answers because you've not defined the norm on $X$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

1. $T\in \mathcal{L}(X, Y) $ is continuous iff $T$ is continuous at $0_X$. (i.e a linear map between two normed spaces either continuous everywhere or discontinuous everywhere.)
2. $T\in \mathcal{L}(X, Y)  $ is continuous at $0$ iff for every sequence $(x_n) \subset X$ with $x_n\to 0 \implies Tx_n \to 0 $

Now, for your question choose,

$f_n(t) =\frac{1}{n} \sin (nt) $

Then try to show :

1. $(f_n) \subset C^1[0, 1] $
2. $f_n \to 0 $ uniformly on $[0, 1]$
3. $A(f_n) $ doesn't converge to $ 0 $ uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

Remember that operator norm is defined only when the operator is continuous (i.e bounded).

Comment: Yes, I understand, but if we talk about the norm, how to find it here? It's just hard to imagine here, although maybe one

Comment: Remember that operator norm is defined only when the operator is continuous (i.e bounded).

Comment: $\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tx\|:\|x\|\le 1\}$ \\For unbounded operator $T$ , the set $\{\|Tx\|:\|x\|\le 1\}$ is not bounded above and $\sup$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the norms on $X,Y$. If $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)|$, then $\|f\|_X = \|f\|_\infty+ \|f'\|_\infty$ and $\|f\|_Y = \|f\|_\infty$.

Hence $\|Af\|_Y = \|f'\|_Y \le \|f\|_X$, and so $A$ is continuous and the norm bounded by one.

Consider $f_n(x) = x^n$ in order to show that this bound is tight.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks! Done.

Comment: @OliverDíaz :-)

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is something wrong I would like to correct it.