# the derivative set of all continuously differentiable functions on a compact set is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $C^1([0,1])$ be the set of all continuously differentiable functions on [0,1], i.e. the derivitave functions are all continuous. Let $C([0,1])$ be the set of all continous functions on [0,1]. Within the sup norm i.e. $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in X} |f(x)|$.

Suppose a linear map $T:C^1([0,1])\to C([0,1])$. Given $Tf=f'$. Suppose I try to prove $T$ is not bounded. I have no idea what is the space? why it is not the same as the set of the derivative of all $f\in C^1([0,1])$

If $f_n:x\to nx \in C^1([0,1])$, then is not $lim_{n\to \infty} f'_n=\infty$?

Comment: It’s not clear what your question is. Are you trying to show that a function has unbounded derivative? This isn’t possible if you assume the function is $C^1$. If you just want to show the space is unbounded, consider $f_n:x\mapsto nx$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that the operator is linear continuous and find its norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424588/how-to-prove-that-the-operator-is-linear-continuous-and-find-its-norm).Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4424588/977780)

Comment: You have to show that a bounded set is mapped to an unbounded set. $\{nx\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not a bounded set. Give it a try with $\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: My confusion is about the definition or terminology. I don't know what I need to show after reading the book and now I am more confused after reading these two comments.

Answer (score 0):

The usual example to show differentiation is unbounded is $f_n(x) = \sin(2\pi nx)$ when you equip both spaces with the infinity norm (in this context this is equal to the $C[0,1]$ norm). Here $T(f_n)(x) = 2\pi n\cos(2\pi n x)$. Note that $\|f_n\|_{\infty}=1$ for all $n$, but $\|Tf_n\|_{\infty}=2\pi n\to\infty.$  This implies that $T$ is unbounded.

Edit to add: It seems maybe your confusion is not understanding operator norms. The norm of $T$ as an operator from $(C^1[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)\to (C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is
$$\sup \frac{\|Tf\|_{\infty}}{\|f\|_{\infty}}.$$
If you find a sequence $f_n$ such that the denominator is 1 but the numerator blows up, this means that $T$ is unbounded.

e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator